# Vertically centering a group of buttons in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to center the buttons to the middle of its parent's div, but have no idea how. I've tried adding `margin: 0 auto` and bootstrap's special class `'center-block'` but it doesn't seem to be working. I suspect it may be clashing with the `display:flex` part of the css, but other than that, I don't know what to do.

Here's a picture of the problem.

[image]

```css
/*--CSS--*/

* {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", "sans-serif" !important;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Raleway", "sans-serif" !important;
}

.page {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.table_cell {
  text-align: center;
}


/*--Page1--*/

.title {}

#mainTitle {
  font-size: 8em;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#mainSub {}


/*--Button--*/

.introButtons {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.buttonBox {}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="firstPage" class="page col-md-12">
  <div class="table_cell col-md-8">
    <div class="introButtons col-md-8">
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#secondPage" class="btn center-block">Who Are We?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#thirdPage" class="btn">Our Projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#fourthPage" class="btn">Our Team</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#fifthPage" class="btn">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any `float` properties declared on the `*col` classes?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError it's bootstrap 3 so i suppose yes

Comment: you code is very strange, a lot of col-* inside other col-*

Comment: would removing the 'col' classes solve the problem?

Comment: you can try as i don't see the utility here

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** (If you want to change your HTML part)

You can use bootstrap **`offset`** classes. More help on **[offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting)**

Replace **`introButtons col-sm-8`** to **`introButtons col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2`**

```css
* {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", "sans-serif" !important;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Raleway", "sans-serif" !important;
}

.page {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.table_cell {
  text-align: center;
}

#mainTitle {
  font-size: 8em;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="firstPage" class="page col-md-12">
  <div class="table_cell col-md-8">
    <div class="introButtons col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#secondPage" class="btn center-block">Who Are We?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#thirdPage" class="btn">Our Projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#fourthPage" class="btn">Our Team</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#fifthPage" class="btn">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2** (If you want to change your CSS part)

Just add below css in your custom css file

```
.introButtons.col-md-8 {
  margin: auto;
  float: none;
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", "sans-serif" !important;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Raleway", "sans-serif" !important;
}

.page {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.table_cell {
  text-align: center;
}

#mainTitle {
  font-size: 8em;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.introButtons.col-md-8 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="firstPage" class="page col-md-12">
  <div class="table_cell col-md-8">
    <div class="introButtons col-md-8">
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#secondPage" class="btn center-block">Who Are We?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#thirdPage" class="btn">Our Projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#fourthPage" class="btn">Our Team</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonBox col-md-3">
        <a href="#fifthPage" class="btn">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well i don't agree a lot with the first one as it's seems more a hack in order to override bootstrap syle, i think it's better to remove the col-md-8 and add more style. But the second solution is the best if we want to use Bootstrap like it is.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes I have given the OP two options if he want to change in html or css part. Solution 1 is the standard way and 2nd solution is the fix if he doesn't want to change html